# Adding a class to a backbone form

Tags: backbone-forms

I tried add a class attribute for a complete form. But I couldn't do it.
As the forms extends of Backbone.View I thought the correct way to get it was:

```
var form = new Backbone.Form({
        model: myModel,
        className: 'myClass'
      }).render();
```

And also I tried:

```
    var MyForm = Backbone.Form.extend({
        className: 'myClass'

        schema: {
            field1:       'Text'
        }
    });

var form = new MyForm({
    model: myModel
}).render();
```

But in both cases the output is:

```
<form data-fieldsets>
    <fieldset data-fields>
        //Code of form...
```

And I think the output would be:

```
<form class="myClass" data-fieldsets>
    <fieldset data-fields>
        //Code of form...
```

Comment: Have you considered using a template?

Comment: Yes, but the only thing that I need is add a class. I don't understand why for that I have to create a template. Also like I said, Backbone-forms extends from Backbone.View so the "className" parameter should be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the $el and adding it there ?

```
 form.$el.attr("class", "testing");
```

live example

http://jsfiddle.net/c5QHr/228/